# How to change Image source according to situation

Tags: react-native

*When component renders first time `this.props.navigation.getParam('Image')` comes undefined so `<Image>` takes  `this.state.Image` and when `this.props.navigation.getParam('Image')`  doesn't come undefined, I takes this as Image. But when I press long to button, I want to Image default value as `require('../Images/add2.png')`. I couldn't do this. Any help*

```
state= {
  Images : require('../Images/add2.png'),
}

    render() {

    return (
         <View>
    <TouchableOpacity   onPressIn={() => this.setState({ buttonPress: 'short' })} 
                        onLongPress={() => this.setState({ buttonPress: 'long' })} 
                        onPressOut={() => {
                            const { buttonPress } = this.state; 
                            if (buttonPress === 'short')
                            {

                            }
                            else if (buttonPress === 'long')
                            {
                                this.setState({ ButtonImage: require('../Images/add2.png') });
                            }
                            this.setState({ buttonPress: 'none' });
                        }}>
       --------->    <Image source={ this.props.navigation.getParam('Image') !== undefined ? { uri: this.props.navigation.getParam('Image') } : this.state.Images } style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }} />

    </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have 2 `<Image>` one for 'require' one for uri.

```
return (
     <View>
<TouchableOpacity   
   onPressIn={() => this.setState({ buttonPress: 'short' })} 
   onLongPress={() => this.setState({ buttonPress: 'long' })} 
   onPressOut={() => {
     const { buttonPress } = this.state; 
     if (buttonPress === 'short'){


     }
     else if (buttonPress === 'long'){
        this.setState({ ButtonImage: require('../Images/add2.png') });
     }
     this.setState({ buttonPress: 'none' });
   }}>
   {this.state.localImage?<Image source={ require('../Images/add2.png') } style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }} />
   :
    <Image source={ uri:this.state.image } style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }} />
    }

</TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
```

)

Save you want to display a local file ('../Images/add2.png') set `this.state.localImage` to true and save the urls in `this.state.image`

Comment: this.props.navigation.getParam('Image') is undefined. When I send prop to this component, this.props.navigation.getParam('Image') is defined. if this.props.navigation.getParam('Image') is defined, I want to set my Image with this.  But when press button long, I want it to change as default Image.   Problem starts here, this.props.navigation.getParam('Image') is still defined so it takes this as Image.

Comment: yes, when you press button long set `this.state.localImage` to true! that will make the other image disapear and shows the default one